# how to scroll to a link without jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever I am applying this code why the link suddenly jumps to ABOUT without scrolling effect

```
$("#start1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var section = this.href, 
        sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
        window.location.hash = sectionClean;
    });
});
```

the html code is here

```
<a href="#about" id="start1" class="scroll"style="text-decoration:none;position:absolute;right:145px;top:30px;font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px;display:block;" onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="small(this)">ABOUT US</a>
```

and

```
<div  id="about" style="position:absolute;top:1311px;width:1348px;height:657px;background-color:black;opacity:0.9;z-index:-999;display:block;">
```

Do i need to download any plugin ? Please help I am new to it

Comment: Have you included `jQuery`?

Comment: no how to do that.. Actually i know some effects but not properly.. most of the time i have followed instructions written to do anything... Can u help me out please ?

Comment: Add this in your <head> section of your html page: 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and then follow the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

I have use class ('.scroll') for this if you want id then use id $('#start1')

Try this:

```
$('.scroll').click(function() {
    // your code.

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
        window.location.hash = sectionClean;
    });
});
```

The 'swing' is there to set the easing. Check out http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for more info.

Comment: No need to add any plugin using jquery it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't wrapped this code in the $(document).ready()
. Without seeing all your code I wouldn't know if this is the actual case but give it a go.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var section = this.href,
            sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
            window.location.hash = sectionClean;
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcw52fqL/1/)

Comment: Actually, yours is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/dcw52fqL/ have you placed this code in the document ready wrapper?

Comment: yeah its working fine in jsfiddle but not on my page

Comment: That suggests it's something else wrong on your page, not the code you've provided

Comment: can u please have a look at my code.. Actually i am not getting it    ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but you need to return false to a click, to cancel the link propagation and allowing the scrolls to work just fine.

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    //your code

    return false;
});
```